# Bad request error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`undefined method name for #<StockQuote::NoDataForStockError:0x007fea46e5fd70>`

I'm using the 'stock_quote' gem found here to fetch data about various stocks https://github.com/tyrauber/stock_quote

I only get an error sometimes when I refresh the browser, but other times the application works fine without me changing any of the code. I think the main issue is a bad request error, but I don't know what to do. I'm new to programming so I'm not sure which one of these is needed to solve the error, so I just provided them all. Like I said, the error only appears sometimes, which is very frustrating. Hope someone can help me, thanks!

Here is the error page that appears in my browser:

```
Showing /Users/frank/Desktop/projects/final-investing/app/views/stock/index.html.erb where line #37 raised:

undefined method 'name' for #<StockQuote::NoDataForStockError:0x007fea433235e0>

Extracted source (around line #9):

7. def self.new_stock_lookup(ticker)

8. looked_up_stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker)

9.     return nil unless looked_up_stock.name

10.    

11. new_stock = new(ticker:looked_up_stock.symbol,

12. name:looked_up_stock.name,
```

Here is the console error:

```
BAD REQUEST] https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%20IN%20('FB')&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=
Rendered stock/_popular_stocks.html.erb (2271.7ms)
Rendered stock/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2277.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2283ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Here's my Stock model

```
class Stock < ApplicationRecord

def self.new_stock_lookup(ticker)
    looked_up_stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker)
    return nil unless looked_up_stock.name

new_stock = new(ticker:looked_up_stock.symbol,
                  name:looked_up_stock.name,
         current_price:looked_up_stock.last_trade_price_only,
     one_year_estimate:looked_up_stock.oneyr_target_price,
        percent_change: (looked_up_stock.oneyr_target_price -
looked_up_stock.last_trade_price_only) / looked_up_stock.last_trade_price_only)
    new_stock
  end
```

Comment: If that's an ActiveRecord Model then you're missing that field. Check your schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with returning `nil` on quote retrieval error, just do:

```
# return nil unless looked_up_stock.name
looked_up_stock.try(:name) || return nil
```

Sometimes the quote is not available and you receive an instance of an error class, that in turn has no `name` method.

The better handling would definitely be smth like:

```
return nil unless StockQuote::Quote === looked_up_stock # or what class is expected
```

or:

```
return nil if looked_up_stock.is_a?(StockQuote::NoDataForStockError)
```